# An small gap (may be padding or margin) just in iPad (Safari or Chrome)

Tags: html, css, ipad, browser, safari

We designed some websites, these websites dont't have any problem in IE, FireFox, Chrome or Opera in Windows or Linux or Mac.

I checked my websites in iPad (Safari or Chrome), in both browser I have an small gap in right of my page !

I use Eric Meyer’s reset css : http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

for example I take an screen shot :
[image]

This is a `<div>` layer, and this is css style:
[image]

What should I do to solve this problem ?

**UPDATE:**

This is HTML code :

```
<div id="footer">
    <a href="http://domain.com">My WebShop V1.0</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Term of use</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Jobs</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Advertisment</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SiteMap</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    &copy; 2013 My WebShop - Allrights reserved.
    <br />
    <a href="#" >Designed and Developed by IITA</a>
</div>
```

CSS Code:

```
#footer {
background-color: #D6D5CF;
text-align: center;
line-height: 18px;
padding: 20px;
color: #000000;
direction: rtl;
font: 11px Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
```

**UPDATE 2:**

I found new thing,
before this layer (I mean footer) I have another layer :

```
<div class="mainPage center width990">
       ....
</div>
```

the CSS code is :

```
.mainPage {
    min-height: 800px;
    padding: 5px;
}

.width990 {
    width: 990px;
}

.center {
    margin: 0px auto;
}
```

When I delete `padding` from `.mainPage` and `width` from `.width990` the problem will solve !
but this layer (`.mainPage`) is not parent of `#footer`, `#footer` is after `.mainPage` !

Is this a BUG ?

Comment: can you fiddle it for better picture?

Comment: also please post your code here and not an image of it.

Comment: @PatrickEvans I found new result, I posted in `Update 2`

Comment: is your mainPage and footer wrapped by another div or some other element or are they just in the <body> tag

Comment: this tags are just in `<body>` tag and for body I have just `background-color` property